# I can't keep Willis alive (spoiler)

Tags: far-cry-3

I'm at the point where Willis has repaired the plane, and we are fighting off the remaining attackers. I can't get past it since he gets killed in like five seconds. I don't even have time to set any mines up or place any C4 before we are overwhelmed, and he charges into the open, right into enemy fire.

How should I keep him alive? He doesn't seem to have the sense to take cover. I'm playing on "normal" difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

This may seem crazy but it worked for me. Meat Shield. You must take the damage on and off for Willis.

Answer (score 0):

I used C4 and my anti-personnel mines at the beginning to kill the amored enemies. As soon as they where gone I used my grenades and fire arrows, wich are far more effective then molotoves.

A good tactic is not to stay at the plane but to go to the houses and open the fire from there, because the enemies will shoot at you so Willis will be safe.

And last but not least, do what Young Guilo said, use a [human shield](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQnEBSwdAXw&feature=kp) (yourself). It is a big advantage if you have  skilled first aid and all health-fields.